# `getaddressinfo` incorrect output for `ismine`

Tags: bitcoin-core, multi-signature, change

Running Core, trying to verify that I infact control a change address before I sign and broadcast a txn. But I can't find any way to list all future change addresses.

I searched and found `listaddressgroupings` but that only seems to show previously used change addresses.

Sipa on IRC suggested I try `getaddressinfo`, but I was alarmed when the output said `ismine:false`

I then tried using `getaddressinfo` again, but this time with one of the already used change addresses that already has coins. I used the first output from `listaddressgroupings`, but then again it returned `ismine:false`

So I believe there is a bug with the "ismine" output

Specter Desktop originally set up this wallet as a watch-only wallet in Core

Does anyone know how to view all future change addresses in Core? Specter wallet can show these to me. I believe Electrum can as well if I remember correctly.

---

edit

`getwalletinfo` output:

```
22:44:52
￼
getwalletinfo


22:44:52
￼
{
  "walletname": "specter3c64f804925fff38\\mymultisig",
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "format": "bdb",
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "unconfirmed_balance": 0.00000000,
  "immature_balance": 0.00000000,
  "txcount": 64,
  "keypoololdest": 1635129892,
  "keypoolsize": 0,
  "keypoolsize_hd_internal": 0,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "private_keys_enabled": false,
  "avoid_reuse": false,
  "scanning": false,
  "descriptors": false
}
```

Comment: and if those balances in the output for getwalletinfo are supposed to show my BTC, they are wrong... the Overview tab clearly shows my correct BTC amounts, and they are not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I believe there is a bug with the "ismine" output

This is expected behavior. Your wallet is a watch only wallet (as it says `"private_keys_enabled": false,`) which means that the wallet is itself unable to spend coins associated with any addresses it is tracking. Furthermore, it is a legacy wallet (because it says `"descriptors": false`) which means that the meaning of `ismine` is somewhat complicated.

For legacy watch only wallets, `ismine` will always be `false` because the wallet itself lacks the private keys necessary to spend the Bitcoin.

> Does anyone know how to view all future change addresses in Core? Specter wallet can show these to me. I believe Electrum can as well if I remember correctly.

Because Specter set up the wallet, you should be using Specter to view everything. Your type of wallet is not capable of generating future addresses, particularly the multisigs that you are using.

Additionally, it is not particularly useful for you to look for your addresses in Bitcoin Core. The private keys are not handled by Bitcoin Core; even if this wallet is watching for transactions to your addresses, you may not be able to spend them. You should be looking at the software or hardware which contains your private keys.